# Airflow Metadata DB = airflow_db?

Tags: airflow

I have a project requirement to back-up Airflow Metadata DB to some data warehouse (but not using an Airflow DAG). At the same time, the requirement mentions some connection called `airflow_db`.

I am quite new to Airflow, so I googled a bit on the topic. I am a bit confused about this part. Our Airflow Metadata DB is PostgreSQL (this is built from docker-compose, so I am tinkering on a local install), but when I look at Connections in Airflow Web UI, it says `airflow_db` is MySQL.

[image]

I initially assumed that they are the same, but by the looks of it, they aren't? Can someone explain the difference and what they are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow creates `airflow_db` Conn Id with MySQL by default (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/41bf172c1dc75099f4f9d8b3f3350b4b1f523ef9/airflow/utils/db.py#L86))

Default connections are not really useful in production system. It's just a long list of stuff that you are probably not going to use.

Airflow 1.1.10 introduced the ability not to create the default list by setting:
`load_default_connections = False` in `airflow.cfg` (See [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/7629))

To give more background the connection list is where hooks find the information needed in order to connect to a service. It's not related to the backend database. Though the backend is db like any db and if you wish to allow hooks to interact with it you can define it in the list like any other connection (which is probably why you have this as option in the default).